# Set 3D cursor position while left-click selection is enabled (2.8)

Tags: 3d-cursor

I decided to switch to the new Blender 2.8 default selection mode, left-click.
But then... How do I set the 3D cursor position ?
left click does nothing, while right click brings a contextual menu.

Thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Shift right-click (in edit mode). No need to use the toolbar icon!

Comment: thanks ! works in object mode, too.

Comment: True! I tend to use it so often that it's become automatic and I don't always notice which mode I'm in! :^)

Answer (score 3):

You have to click on the cursor icon on the left-hand corner

[image]

Comment: ok, thanks. Too bad that it requires an extra click.